# crystal reports : truncate leading zeroes (0's)?

Tags: crystal-reports

In crystal reports, how do you remove leading zeroes?

I realize for the number 0000012313, you can use right(0000012313, 5) and return 12313; however this is presuming this is a fixed length.

any ideas?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `VAL()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Use cint(00000123)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if isnumeric({your field}) then
 totext(tonumber({yourfield}),0)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you just googled and found out that none of these answers worked for Crystal Reports, you should try this:

```
totext(tonumber(string), '#');
```

This is also fixing the additional comma error